# Need to update fields in membership - Is there a global change function similar to the one on Raisers Edge to do this?

Tags: civimember

Need to update fields in membership - Is there a global change function similar to the one on Raisers Edge to do this?

Need to update one membership field in CIVICRM to the same option.  Is there a way to do this without doing it manually?

Comment: Hi Ann Marie, it will probably help if you can outline the scenario in a bit more detail. Is this a Custom Field, hence a a Custom field group/set that is used for Memberships (as opposed to Contacts). And what do you mean by 'the same option'. And have you explored Batch Updating (from the Actions menu on Find Memberships)

Comment: I agree with Pete - if you could say a little bit more about what you're trying to do - which field is it?  How many memberships? Folks could tell you if it can be globally changed.